# Add glyhicons to title of jquery FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar

I am trying to add some glyhicon to the title of jquery FullCalendar, but am having issues.

I am passing in the following array:

```
result << {
  :id => c["id"],
  :description => c["description"],
  :title => '<i class="icon-lg fa fa-calendar"></i>',
  :start => result_datetime,
  :end => result_datetime+60*60*3,
  :url => micropost_url(c["id"], format: :html),
  :allDay => false
}
```

The title just shows up as ''. Is there a way to force javascript to evaluate that HTML inside the json? Or should I be inserting something else into the title field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to append/put your HTML on [`eventRender`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/)

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    element.find('.fc-event-title').html('<i class="icon-lg fa fa-calendar"></i>');
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h9cC6/787/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
'<i class="icon-lg fa fa-calendar"></i>'.html_safe
```

Comment: `html_safe` only in ruby.